# Cloning enum mapped types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to do a two level clone as described below. Unfortunately even though i use the same enitity type, TS can't detect that there will be a type match. Is there any good way around this?

```
enum Name {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b',
}

interface Types {
    [Name.A]: number;
    [Name.B]: string;
}

type Mapping = { [T in Name]: {[key: string]: Types[T]}};

/** Perform two level clone. */
function cloneMapping(m: Mapping) : Mapping {

    // Top level clone to preserve type.
    const result = {...m};

    for (const key in Name) {
        const name: Name = Name[key as keyof typeof Name];

        const left = result[name]; // Type: { [key: string]: number;} | { [key: string]: string; }
        const right = m[name]; // Type: { [key: string]: number;} | { [key: string]: string; }

        result[name] = {...m[name]};
        // ERROR: Type '{ [key: string]: number; } | { [key: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: number; } & { [key: string]: string; }'.
    }
    return result;   
}
```

### Answer

[Linda Paiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431574/linda-paiste) has used a generic arrow function which allows the concrete types to be preserved. Further building on this idea, I've reduced the function to:

```
function cloneMapping2(m: Mapping): Mapping {
    const result = { ...m };
    Object.values(Name).forEach(<T extends Name>(name: T) => {
        result[name] = { ...m[name] };
    });
    return result;
}
```

Or a further reduced, but not exactly equivalent version:

```
const cloneMapping3 = (m: Mapping): Mapping =>
    Object
        .values(Name)
        .reduce(<T extends Name>(result: Mapping, value: T) =>
            ({ ...result, [value]: { ...m[value] } }), m);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you base your typings on `keyof SomeType`, typescript doesn't understand that you are dealing with the *same* key on both `left` and `right`.  It knows that both could be either a `number` or a `string` object, but it doesn't know that they are the same as each other.

What I did to fix this was to move to looping logic into a function `handleKey` which is a generic based on the specific key.  If you type `name` as `const name: Name` it will no longer work because that type is too broad to ensure matching.  But when `name` is inferred to be a specific member of the enum, `typeof Name[K]`, then there are no errors.

```
function cloneMapping(m: Mapping) : Mapping {

    const result = {...m};

    const handleKey = <K extends keyof typeof Name>( key: K ) => {
        const name = Name[key];

        let left = result[name];
        const right = m[name];

        left = right;
        result[name] = {...m[name]};
    }

    for (const key in Name) {
        handleKey(key as keyof typeof Name);
    }

    return result;   
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/vWkdLw)